# Juno no wireless after upgrading from loki

Tags: wifi, networking, release-juno

I've just installed Juno and wireless networking is not working.

Clicking the networking item in the top right, it just gives a switch for Wired and  the Network settings... items. There is no entry for wireless at all.

In the network setting page the left hand column lists Eathernet, ad virtual devices. Again no entry for Wireless at all.

Doing lshw -C network I get a section for wireless device

```
  *-network
   description: Network controller
   product: BCM4322 802.11a/b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller
   vendor: Broadcom Limited
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   version: 01
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=b43-pci-bridge latency=0
   resources: irq:20 memory:d3200000-d3203fff
```

but doing rfkill list there is nothing for wireless

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

not sure what to do from here. I'm currently away from home so can't use a wired network connection.

Wireless networking works fine if I run from the USB drive, and I ticked the install 3rd party drivers during installation. I'm running on a 2009 macbook pro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out to be a relatively easy fix. I just needed to install the `bcmwl-kernel-source` driver from the app center once I managed to get a wired Ethernet connection.

Comment: I think you should accept your own answer, then. :-)